# Why does collecting dataset fail with org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I use Spark with YARN cluster manager.

I create a dataset from a Cassandra table with around 700 rows with 5 columns in that and one of the column with data in JSON format. The amount of data is in MB only.

I run `spark-shell` with:

- spark.executor.memory=4g
- spark.driver.memory=2g

I am getting this error:

> org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to bosirahtaicas02.bscuat.local/172.17.0.1:53093 at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:323)

while I am trying to collect data from my `dataFrame`

I run the following piece of code directly in spark-shell (line by line):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

import org.json._
import java.sql.Timestamp

val sqc = new SQLContext(sc)
val csc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)

val allRecordsDF = sqc.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").
    option("table", "xyz").
    option("keyspace", 'pqr").load().cache()

val allRowsDF = allRecordsDF.select(allRecordsDF.col("record_type"), allRecordsDF.col("process_time"))

val allPatientsTS = allRowsDF.where(allRowsDF("record_type") === "patient").select("process_time").sort("process_time")
```

Here when I am trying to collect `allPatientsTS` `Dataframe` it is showing error.

Comment: Can you attach the entire stack trace from `spark-shell` and `yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>`? Can you also do `yarn version`?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting my notes about [FetchFailedException](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-TaskRunner-FetchFailedException.html):

> `FetchFailedException` exception may be thrown when a task runs (and `ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator` did not manage to fetch shuffle blocks).

The root cause of a `FetchFailedException` is *usually* because the executor (with the BlockManager for the shuffle blocks) is lost (i.e. no longer available) due to:

- OutOfMemoryError could be thrown (aka OOMed) or some other unhandled exception.
- The cluster manager that manages the workers with the executors of your Spark application, e.g. YARN (this is the case here), enforces the container memory limits and eventually decided to kill the executor due to excessive memory usage.

You should review the logs of the Spark application using web UI, Spark History Server or cluster-specific tools like `yarn logs -applicationId` for Hadoop YARN.

A solution is *usually* to tune the memory of your Spark application.

As you can see, it's hard to say exactly what caused the FetchFailedException without extensive review of your dataset (most importantly its size and partitioning scheme on Spark) and logs in YARN.

Comment: If that worked for you, accept the answer for future readers. Thanks.

Comment: DivasNikhra: Seems like this answer is correct. Why dont you accept this answer by @JacekLaskowski as owner. It would be pointer to other users as well. Not accepting have many meanings to other users. So pls accept if its okay for you. or comment why its not working or what kind of clarification needed here. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ram, though Jacek suggestion is very important I don't see any specific solution in that answer

Comment: In Jaceks answer the clearly mentioned **"A solution is usually to tune the memory of your Spark application."** , you did the same thing as well..... this type of issues are tricky to tell exactly same of what you are looking for. please. try to understand that its not logic of the program to execute and get the output.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this similar issue. To find a solution I have spent a few weeks to implement suggestions by many sources those are: configuration, partitioning, memory fraction increment, network timeout and so on. However, all failed to provide me with a solution.

Finally, I figured out the issue in my small cluster. The workers node's RAM size is 8 GB, and I have configured the worker memory 6 GB (for larger overhead) in .conf file. Unfortunately, a background service in one of the workers is consuming 3 GB memory and that's why the issue is occurring (as all the workers are seeking to map 6GB memory for each). I downgraded to 4GB worker memory in the spark-defaults.conf file, and now I am not facing this issue. 
N.B: check all the workers whether any other service is consuming the significant amount of resource.